# Shooting a bullet in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

Imagine I was in space holding a gun and I shot a bullet from it.

Do I go back? Or does the bullet move forward? Or both of us go in the same speed at different directions? Or what? Please Explain.

If any of this is impossible please imagine it isn't (as for example the need of oxygen to shot).

Sorry for any language mistakes, I'm from a non English-speaking country.

Comment: [Conservation of momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation). Apply it.

Comment: Yes, you go back.   If the bullet weighs 0.1 lbs and you (and the gun you're holding) weigh 200 lbs.   The bullet will shoot forward at 1,000 meters per second and you would move backward, 1/2000th of that or 0.5 meters per second.  That's conservation of momentum.  Guns can fire in space because the gunpowder is oxidized, it doesn't need oxygen to fire, in fact, guns might fire slightly better in space cause there's no atmosphere in the barrel to slow down the bullet.

Answer (score 3):

First, the chemical reaction that takes place in the cartridge of a gun produces high temperature, high-pressure gas, without the need for *external* oxygen.  The gases then push the gun and the bullet apart.

Secondly, the bullet will leave the barrel with a certain amount of momentum, found by multiplying the mass of the bullet by the velocity of the bullet.  Conservation of momentum requires that the gun, along with everything it rigidly attached to, will recoil with the same momentum.  Since the gun and attachments is usually *much* more massive than the bullet, the gun will recoil at a much lower velocity.

Next, the gases that are generated by the explosion of the propellant will follow the bullet out the barrel of the gun.  These gases, equal in mass to the mass of the pre-firing propellant will travel faster than the bullet and will carry even more momentum.  So, in turn, this process will require an increase in the reverse velocity of the shooter.  It's as if the shooter threw a rock and then set off a small short-lived rocket.

A *recoilless* rifle functions by taking some of this gas and venting it *backwards* from the gun.  With the right amount of back venting, you can reduce the recoil to a small amount.

Finally, it is unlikely that the recoil force on the gun-carrying astronaut will be directed exactly through the astronaut's centre of mass.  So, besides recoiling backwards, the shooter will be rotating...